# PostgreSQL - FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "myuser"

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu

I just installed PostGreSQL in my Ubuntu Box, and the first thing I want to do is to create a database. I read the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/tutorial-createdb.html), and it simply says type createdb. Once I typed in that command, PostgreSQL gave me an error: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "myuser". I assume that this is because "myuser" does not have the right administration privileges in the database. Is there an easy way to add that priviliges ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why would you close this.  I mean, if you can migrate it somewhere, yes, but just close w/o migrating?  wtf.

Answer (score 2):

The postgresql usually creates a default user postgres. You would have entered a password during installation for this user. If you remember you can use it.

Otherwise, you can add an entry in the pg_hba.conf file to enable your localhost to login without any password for psql command.

A sample entry would be

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

Comment: Do I need to restart the database, because that entry did not do anything. I typed $pg_ctl and it says command not found

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, create a user first?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-createuser.html

Comment: I tried that and it says: createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "myuser". I thought the database was not running. I typed $ createuser. PostgreSQL asked me "ENter name of role to add". I thought, hmmm, the database is running