# Why "host:localhost" must be deleted from database.yml under Cent OS 6, PostgreSQL 9.4 and Rails 3.2, or get a error: Ident authentication failed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, thinking-sphinx

All config files described here are the same as my Mac OS's and all works fine in Mac OS.

I got the same error in CentOS 6 x86_64:

```
Ident authentication failed for user 'abelard'
```

When running the following two commands:

```
1. rake db:create
2. psql -d testforabelard2 -U abelard -h localhost
```

I got the same error after trying these answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8102547/1054800) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942678/1054800).

My `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/pg_hba.con`'s content is as follows:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

And there is a blank file `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/pg_ident.con`

My `database.yml`'s content is as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: social_stream_development
  pool: 5
  username: abelard
  password: password

  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

I found a resolution: the error disappear after deleting `host:localhost` from the above `database.yml`. But I can not delete `host:localhost` because there is a `sql_host = localhost` generated automatically when using `think-sphinx` for full-text search.

And for offering the same params as my Mac OS's, I altered `PostgreSQL`'s user `abelard` :

```
testforabelard2=# \du
            List of roles
 Role name | Attributes  | Member of 
-----------+-------------+-----------
 abelard   | Superuser   | {}
           : Create role   
           : Create DB     
 postgres  | Superuser   | {}
           : Create role   
           : Create DB
```

And I can run the command without `-h localhost` successfully:

```
psql -d testforabelard2 -U abelard
```

I don't know what things I miss, what should I do for correct this error? Any advice will be welcome!

Comment: Does switching it from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` help?

Comment: @pat Thank you! I have resolved it and not updated here because I was busy in other things, I am sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved myself easily through moving `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/pg_hba.con` to `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.con`.

The reason for this mistake I made is that I referred to my Mac OS's position of the file `pg_hba.con`.

Of course, I thank this early blog [“FATAL: IDENT AUTHENTICATION FAILED”, OR HOW COOL IDEAS GET BAD USAGE SCHEMAS](http://www.depesz.com/2007/10/04/ident/) , which reminded me to realise the wrong place of the above file!